# Blocked process state affect on thread state within process?

Tags: windows, process, threads, multi-threaded

If multiple threads are running within a process and the process goes from running to blocked state then do all the threads within the process automatically go into blocked state as well?

If the answer is OS specific then we can assume that the OS being used is Windows

Comment: "Blocked" is not a process state in Windows. Processes don't have scheduling states. Threads do. Yes, there is an NtSuspendProcess native API, but it works by calling NtSuspendThread on each of the process's threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you determining the *blocked* status of the process in question?

I recommend using the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) from sysinternals.com, as it will tell you as much as you can know about the Windows processes running on your machine.